# It is possible to have a single .env file and pick variables based on the python environment?

Tags: python, environment-variables

I have seen that many information say that must be dev.env file and pro.env file, it is possible to have both enviroments information on a single .env file?

For example

```
#.env file

[Production]
DATABASE=123.34.54
PASSWORD=9874
USERNAME="admin"

[Development]
DATABASE=127.0.0.1
PASSWORD=""
USERNAME=""
```

Comment: Of course it's _possible_. Whether there's currently a _tool_ set up to do that (or you're willing and able to write one) I don't know; most of the `dotenv`-style tools I've used wouldn't support that.

Comment: What tool is that, every blog or tutorial only shows how to export variables using dotenv, but no one export base on the environment wether is prod or dev, thanks

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying - I don't know if there's a tool that already does that; maybe you could _write it yourself_.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime to make it works i did everything in python files

```
app/|
    |-main.py

config/|
       |-config.py
```

Inside config.py

```
environment = { 
        "Development":{
            "STATE":"dev",
            "SMS_API_KEY":"PWDpwdPWD",
            "SMS_SECRET_KEY":"blaBLAbla",
            "IP_DB":"123.45.67.89",
            "DATABASE":"DATABASE_ANY",
            "TABLA":"AnyTable",
            "USER":"myUser"
            ....
       
        },
        "Production":{
            "STATE":"pro",
            "SMS_API_KEY":"AAbbCC",
            "SMS_SECRET_KEY":"ProKeyBLA",
            "IP_DB":"10.20.29.49",
            "DATABASE":"PROD_DATABASE",
            ...   
        }
```

}

How to access to the environment

```
env = os.environ.get("environment") 
print(env)
```

Also you can check in the shell

```
echo $environment_variable_name
```

At any file you import config file

```
from config import config as cf

env = os.environ.get("environment")
print("Environ=",cf.environment[env]["IP_DB"])

# Print the IP from Development because in the server already exists the variable Development just to let you know fellas, any question just let me know

Environ= 123.45.67.89
```

Print the IP from Development because in the server already exists the variable Development just to let you know fellas, any question just let me know